# Async download file in c#

Tags: c#

I need help to improve this code but I do not understand where I made a mistake. The file is downloaded but in a corrupted format. I am using cookies also which is a required part of this method.

```
/*Downlod task */
public static async Task<int> CreateDownloadTask(string urlToDownload,string sDestinationPath, string cookiedstr)
{
    int BufferSize = 4096;
    int receivedBytes = 0;
    int totalBytes = 0;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookiedstr);

    using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(urlToDownload))
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read = 0;
            totalBytes = Int32.Parse(client.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentLength]);
            var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                FileStream file = new FileStream(sDestinationPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.WriteTo(file);
                file.Flush();
                file.Close();
                buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                receivedBytes += read;
                Console.WriteLine(receivedBytes + " " + totalBytes);
                // DownloadBytesProgress args = new DownloadBytesProgress(urlToDownload, receivedBytes, totalBytes);
            }
            ms.Close();
        }
        return receivedBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: If file size is `totalBytes` then you should use that (instead of `BufferSize`) to read and write to disk. If it's shorter then...it will be _padded_ with zeros, it it's longer then you will save just first chunk. Also you don't need to go through a `MemoryStream` if you already a `FileStream` (which btw should be enclosed in `using`).

Comment: Thank you  :)  Glen i will try for it

Comment: That looks like http, have you considered how the file contents is encoded when transfered?